# ArangoDB installation in Windows 8

Tags: installation, arangodb

I [downloaded ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/download) version 2.3.4 and tried to install it on my Windows 8 OS.

During the installation, I had been prompted to choose the default path or *All Users* and such. I opted for default path, which installed the application under the path `C:\Program Files\ArangoDB 2.3.4\bin`. After successfully installed ArangoDB, I tried to open the console and typed `arangod.exe`. It prompted me some error message:

```
ERROR cannot open datafile "c:\program files\arangodb 2.3.4 ....\logfile-207139.db': 'No Error'
ERROR cannot open datafile "c:\program files\arangodb 2.3.4 ....\logfile-207139.db": system error
ERROR could not inspect WAL logfiles: system error
FATAL unable to start WAL logfile manager
```

I am not sure what's going wrong, but I tried uninstall and reinstall with *All User* option and it worked by showing me

> ArangoDB is ready for business. Have fun!

However, the ArangoDB was installed under the `C:\Users\Public\Documents\ArangoDB 2.3.4` folder, which I think is not appropriate. Anyone knows how to install by selecting the default path on Windows 8?

Comment: If you install ArangoDB under "C:\Program Files\" you need a user with write access to the directory C:\Program Files\. Did you try to install it as service? This should start ArangoDB automatically with a suitable user (at least in Windows 7).

Comment: Thanks for help. I have tried to install the service as you told by following the link https://docs.arangodb.com/Installing/Windows.html. But it ends up the same. I checked on my services ArangoDB is running. I tried to add "Everyone" to have the full write access on folders etc and var but remain the same.

Comment: When you say "ArangoDB" service is running, then the server should already be up. Can you use the task manager to check, if there is a process "arangod"? Can you try "arangosh" to connect to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found a solution on this. Go to the var folder security tab and click on Advanced then Disable the inheritance. It works for me now

Comment: Would you please add a screenshot?